# superscript for QTableWidget header

Tags: qt, qstring, qtablewidget, superscript

I'm learning QT and have to design a table like this

[image: example]

I need "m2" with "2" as superscript.

Here is my code:

```
ui.tableWidget->horizontalHeaderItem(0)->setText("Date");
ui.tableWidget->horizontalHeaderItem(0)->setBackgroundColor(QColor(217, 217, 217));
ui.tableWidget->horizontalHeaderItem(1)->setText("House address");
ui.tableWidget->horizontalHeaderItem(1)->setBackgroundColor(QColor(217, 217, 217));
ui.tableWidget->horizontalHeaderItem(2)->setText("Area \n [m\u00B2]");
ui.tableWidget->horizontalHeaderItem(2)->setBackgroundColor(QColor(217, 217, 217));
ui.tableWidget->horizontalHeaderItem(3)->setText("Price \n [USD]");
ui.tableWidget->horizontalHeaderItem(3)->setBackgroundColor(QColor(217, 217, 217));
ui.tableWidget->horizontalHeaderItem(4)->setText("Price/Area \n [USD/m\u00B2]");
ui.tableWidget->horizontalHeaderItem(4)->setBackgroundColor(QColor(217, 217, 217));
```

I used "\u00B2" for "2" as superscript but it doesn't work, the background color also does not change. Please help me, many thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `QString("Area \n [m%1]").arg(QChar(0x00B2))` or `QString("Area \n [%1]").arg(QChar(0x33A1))`. It should work with any source encoding.

If it doesn't work, maybe your font doesn't support this symbols to display. If there is no other way you may try to imitate headers by QLabel with HTML like this: `"<B> Area <BR> [m<SUP>2</SUP>] </B>"`. Remember that setting QWidgets to QTableWidget is usually ugly and possibly slow. And you will have bad architecture.

Comment: thanks, your solution is great :). I also found another solution for that below. Btw, do you have any idea for my problem with background color ? I dont know why my command does not work.

Comment: The solution with QChar, of course? Don't know about header colours. Try Googling. At least Qt [had some troubles](https://forum.qt.io/topic/40002/qtablewidget-s-header-background-color-doesn-t-work-in-win7) with it.

Comment: Faced to table views today, looked to the background. QHeaderView processes background incorrectly with default style on Windows 10. If the application style is changed to Fusion or others, it works. And there is a funny workaround: it processes QSS. So, solution 1: `table->setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion"))`; solution 2: [apply QSS](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qheaderview) to the table's header view.

Comment: thanks, i also have another solution  `tableWidget->setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::section { background-color:rgb(217,217,217) }");`

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
ui.tableWidget->horizontalHeaderItem(2)->setText(QString::fromUtf8("Area \n [m\u00B2]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

after searching I found a solution for this, I am not good enough to know why it works but it works fine for me

```
const char s[] = {
    0x6D,               // m
    0xC2, 0xB2,         // superscript two
    0x00                // NUL terminator
};
QString str = QString::fromUtf8(s);
```

and then

```
ui.tableWidget->horizontalHeaderItem(2)->setText("Area \n [m" + str + "]");
```